# SQL query include in CONCAT only if cell is not empty

Tags: php, sql

I am building using `CONCAT` a long string, one cell from DB (`design_name`) is in some rows empty (not `NULL`, just empty). Every single value is separated by `_`
I would like to ignore the value when this cell is empty, because in this case I have double `__` sign in final string. Itried using `CASE` but I get errors.

```
SELECT CONCAT(year,t,id, ' - ', country, '_', year, '_',value, '_', order, 
CASE WHEN design_name != '' THEN '_', design_name, END '_', customer, '_', order) 
AS customer_projects
FROM projects WHERE customer = 'SAMPLE_CUSTOMER' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if design_name is not equal to empty then set it to '_'
so modify != to = will get it working. code below

```
SELECT CONCAT(year, t,id,  ' - ', isnull(country,''), '_', year, '_',
isnull(value,''), '_', isnull(order,''), 
CASE WHEN design_name = '' THEN '_' 
     ELSE design_name END '_', 
     isnull(customer,''), '_', isnull(order,'')) AS customer_projects
FROM projects WHERE customer = 'SAMPLE_CUSTOMER' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

If the fields- country, value, order, customer from projects table allow null then it is advised to use isnull check on them. As in case you get a null value in your query the CONCAT function will return null and query will fail.

Answer (score 1):

in MySQL, Your CASE statement is wrong

Change this

```
CASE WHEN design_name != '' THEN '_', design_name, END
```

to

```
CASE WHEN design_name = '' THEN '_' ELSE design_name END,
```

Answer (score 1):

in MySQL, i would use CONCAT_WS to achieve this as follows, CONCAT_WS will add the first argument in between each value while ignoring NULL values

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('_',CONCAT(year,t,id), country, year,value, order,(CASE WHEN design_name = '' THEN NULL ELSE design_name END), customer, order) AS customer_projects
FROM projects WHERE customer = 'SAMPLE_CUSTOMER' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

your case statement is wrong

```
SELECT CONCAT(year,t,id, ' - ', country, '_', year, '_',value, '_', order, 
CASE WHEN design_name = '' THEN '_' else design_name END,  '_', customer, '_', "order") 
AS customer_projects
FROM projects WHERE customer = 'SAMPLE_CUSTOMER' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```